# Can't create view, no permissions despite added permissions

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

I have a problem with inserting a template. When I run `tde.templateInsert` it returns Invalid permission in response, but I enabled triple indexes in database settings and added permission to the user (added both `tde-admin` and `tde-view`).

I am following this tutorial step by step: https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/template-driven-extraction/

This is the whole error message:

> [javascript] SEC-INVALIDPERM: xdmp:document-insert("/test/myFirstTDE.json", document{object-node{"template":object-node{"context":text{"/Companies"}, ...}}}, (json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), ...), ("TDE", "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde")) -- Invalid permission

> Stack Trace
> In undefined on line 8
> In xdmp:document-insert("/test/myFirstTDE.json", document{object-node{"template":object-node{"context":text{"/Companies"}, ...}}}, (json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>), ...), ("TDE", "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde"))

> In /MarkLogic/tde.xqy on line 58
> In template-insert#4("/test/myFirstTDE.json", Document({"template":{"context":"/Companies", "collections":["source1"], "rows":[...]}}), [{capability:"read", roleId:"16742763111021671912"}, {capability:"update", roleId:"3680293911625886504"}, {capability:"read", roleId:"3680293911625886504"}, ...], "TDE")

Comment: I am seeing the same results. Looking into it, but I think you can work around the issue by changing the third parameter value from  `xdmp.defaultPermissions()` to `null`. Though, it sounds like that should do the same thing based upon documentation from that parameter: "Any permissions to set on the template document. When supplying null as permissions parameter, the inserted template will have the default set of permissions."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce. There appears to be an issue in how `xdmp.defaultPermissions()` are being processed. I have filed a bug with information about how to reproduce this behavior.

In the meantime, you can work around the issue by either relying on some default behaviors for the `$permissions` parameter:

> `$permissions` Any permissions to set on the template document. When supplying null as permissions parameter, the inserted template will have the default set of permissions.
> and using `null` instead of `xdmp.defaultPermissions()`

```
tde.templateInsert(
  "/test/myFirstTDE.json" ,
  myFirstTDE,
  null,
  ["TDE"]
)
```

or explicitly creating the permissions you want to apply:

```
var permissions = [
  xdmp.permission("admin", "read"),
  xdmp.permission("admin", "insert"),
  xdmp.permission("admin", "update")
];
tde.templateInsert(
  "/test/myFirstTDE.json" ,
  myFirstTDE,
  permissions,
  ["TDE"]
)
```

Comment: It is still throwing the same error like: (Permission denied: update /templates/user-template). I can only add tde template when my user have admin role. When I set both tde-admin and tde-view I still have the same error.

Comment: I am able to insert with only `tde-admin` permissions specified (using the last example, just changing `admin` to `tde-admin`). Who are you running the command as, and what permissions do you have?

Comment: Ok so lets create new user. What roles are necessary to be able to add template?

Comment: The `tde-admin` role is required in order to insert a template into the schema database.

Comment: Ok but is there any other roles necessary?